# Ordenação Laravel com Relacionamento

Tags: laravel

Estou querendo fazer uma consulta relacionada, mas a **ordenação deve ser feita por um campo de outra tabela que está no relacionamento.**

```
$consulta       = Dealer::whereIdMarca($codMarca)
                    ->whereIdCidade($codCidade)
                    ->get();
```

### Relacionamento

```
public function order_avg_rating(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\DealerRating", "id_concessionaria")
                ->selectRaw('AVG(rating) as media')
                ->groupBy('id_concessionaria');
}
```

A ordenação seria para os estabelecimentos que tivessem **mais estrelas e mais avaliações**. Não ordena! Além disso, caso eu faça um JOIN direto no **Dealer::** no Controller, **perde todos os relacionamentos** que fiz no Model para outras coisas...

"/

Estou tentando outras coisas:

### Consulta

```
$consulta       = Dealer::whereIdMarca($codMarca)
                    ->whereIdCidade($codCidade)
                    ->where('concessionaria', 'like', '%'.$consultaCon.'%')
                    ->with('order_avg')
                    ->get()
                    ->sortByDesc('order_avg.media, order_avg.qtd_avaliacoes')
                    ->reverse();
```

Estou tentando ordenar pela média e quantidade de avaliações. Mas não aplica o que eu estou fazendo. Não sei o que acontece que não ordena. Ele ordena automaticamente pela ordem de cadastro, possivelmente.

### Model

```
public function order_avg(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Dealer', 'dealer_ratings', 'id_concessionaria', 'id_concessionaria')
                ->withPivot('id_concessionaria')
                ->selectRaw('count(dealer_ratings.id) as qtd_avaliacoes, AVG(rating) as media')
                ->groupBy('dealers.id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido. Fiz com ***Eager Loading***, era o único modo.

```
# Pesquisar na Base de Dados a Consulta do Usuário
$consulta       = Dealer::with(['order_avg'])
                  ->leftJoin('dealer_ratings', function($q){
                     $q->on('dealer_ratings.id_concessionaria', '=', 'dealers.id')
                       ->whereNotIn('id_status', [1, 4]);
                        })
                        ->selectRaw('*, dealers.id, coalesce(count(dealer_ratings.id), 0) as qtd_avaliacoes, coalesce(AVG(rating), 0) as media')
                        ->groupBy('dealers.id')
                        ->orderBy('media', 'desc')
                        ->orderBy('qtd_avaliacoes', 'desc')
                        ->whereIdMarca($codMarca)
                        ->whereIdCidade($codCidade)
                        ->where('concessionaria', 'like', '%'.$consultaCon.'%')
                  ->get();
```

E no **Model Dealer.PHP** apenas fiz a ligação:

```
# Order By Media de Stars
public function order_avg(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\DealerRating', 'id_concessionaria');
}
```

Fazendo assim não perde os outros relacionamentos que existem.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode efetuar um join no seu model `Dealer`

```
Dealer::join('dealer', 'tabela_2.id', '=', 'dealer.relationship_id')->orderBy('table_2.id', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Mas e quanto ao **hasMany** no Model ? Não tem problema ?

Comment: Quando faço isso perco meus relacionamentos... não queria fazer o SELECT gigante no Controller...